# Facing Issue Inserting Hebrew XML data into sql server 2005

Tags: sql, xml, hebrew

I am facing issue while inserting XML data with Hebrew content into Sql Server 2005 Database.

Same data is given below.Thnx in advance.

```
Declare @XML nvarchar(max)

set @XML = 
'

    <Table1>
        <Selected>1</Selected>
        <Resource_Key>הקונסולרית היטל</Resource_Key>
      </Table1>

'
select @xml1

Output ->

  <Table1>     <Selected>1</Selected>      <Resource_Key>?????????? ????</Resource_Key>    </Table1>
```

Note :

When I am appending N when

```
set @XML = 
N'
<Table1>.....</Table1>'

enter code here
```

I am getting desired result .

How can i append the N unicode character before XML to update the same in Database.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `N''` sign also when you want to set a value.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @XML nvarchar(max)

set @XML = N'd0ff867e-c426-4ac2-ad35-6cf18aabf310 303f511d-a99f-463e-ba08-14774ce5b501 Consular Surcharge db95f19b-3122-4408-8594-e9be0a9db17d false 1 הקונסולרית היטל ' 

select @xml
```

The output

d0ff867e-c426-4ac2-ad35-6cf18aabf310 303f511d-a99f-463e-ba08-14774ce5b501 Consular Surcharge db95f19b-3122-4408-8594-e9be0a9db17d false 1 הקונסולרית היטל

**Edit**

I am looking on your question and at the `SET` you didn't uses `N''`

Try this

```
Declare @XML nvarchar(max)

set @XML = N'<Table1>
        <Selected>1</Selected>
        <Resource_Key>הקונסולרית היטל</Resource_Key>
      </Table1>
      '
select @xml
```

Comment: Hi Silagy,Thnx for ur comment.But I have already posted the same within my question.My Query Is that I am passing the XML content in a Sql Parameter of type Nvarchar(max).Now If I read the same using OpenXML Syntax ,I am facing the Issue of "?".  SELECT   Receipt_Place_Holder_Key,
 Resource_Key FROM OpenXml(@intHandle,'/NewDataSet/Table',2)
WITH (  Receipt_Place_Holder_Key VARCHAR(500),
 Resource_Key NVARCHAR(max)) .

Comment: I am facing the Issue while reading the XMl content using OpenXML query as given in my comment!

Comment: Can you post the code how you try to get the XML content using OpenXML

Comment: SELECT Receipt_Place_Holder_Key, Resource_Key FROM OpenXml(@intHandle,'/Table1',1) WITH ( Receipt_Place_Holder_Key VARCHAR(500), Resource_Key NVARCHAR(max))